# "The Silicon Valley credo is driving the society to develop rapidly." Which interpretation is more reasonable?

Tags: sentence-meaning

A sentence in one text says "The Silicon Valley credo is driving the society to develop rapidly.".
I think this sentence has two interpretations:

(1) The content of the Silicon Valley credo is "driving the society to develop rapidly".
(2) The Silicon Valley credo causes the fact that the credo drives the society to develop rapidly.

My textbook says (2) is the right interpretation. Can we judge which interpretation is more reasonable simply from grammar knowledge, not from the context? (i.e. Given only this sentence, are (1) and (2) both reasonable?)

Comment: [It's good to post questions for the layout is more readable.]

Comment: Personally, I find 2) to be pretty awful. Who wrote your textbook? Please post it.

Comment: @Lambie Sincerely sorry. Next time   I will pay more attention.

Comment: No need to apologize. As I asked you above, who wrote the textbook? We aren't supposed to quote books without giving information about it.

Comment: @Lambie Well, I am a Chinese and this is a well-known textbook in China for the preparation of English exams of the graduate entrance text. The book translated the sentence into Chinese, and (1), (2) was translated back into English by myself, so (1), (2) may not be quite well-organized.

Comment: What is the point of back-translation?? If those two sentences are given, only 1) is acceptable. Even more acceptable would be: **The Silicon Valley credo is driving the society to develop rapidly**. It's really quite simple. [you wrote text instead of test.] :)

Comment: @Lambie Well, I mean that except for the sentence structure of (2) is really awful, in the view of simply the sentence meaning, does "The Silicon Valley credo is driving the society to develop rapidly." mean (1) or (2), or both can be reasonable if no context is given, and we need to determine its meaning from the context?

Comment: Driving here means causing x to  happen. The Silicon Valley credo is causing the society to develop rapidly.

Comment: Thanks @Lambie. If you do not mind my disturbing, could you please tell why (1) is not a reasonable understanding?

Comment: You are not "disturbing me" [you probably mean bother but you are not bothering me either), My issue is this: If I read an explanation where the English sounds odd or awkward, I feel a need to "fix it". Generally, when we talk about a credo, we don't say "the content of the credo". We just say: the credo [does or says this or that]. Just like we would not say: the content of the idea. Is that clearer? :)

Comment: @Lambie Then if without context, only given the sentence, is it possible that this sentence could mean either “The credo says the Silicon Valley should drive the society to develop quickly.” or "The Silicon Valley credo is forcing or causing the society to develop rapidly."?

Comment: A **credo** is a statement of beliefs. Presumably the sentence means that the beliefs of the kind of people who work in 'Silicon Valley' are causing society to develop rapidly.

Comment: @Asigan  I think you are making things too complicated.  *Credo* is the subject of the sentence.  It's the "Silicon Valley credo", but we don't know whether that's because it's *from* Silicon Valley, or *about* Silicon Valley, or what.  All we know is that the credo is doing something to society.  The sentence doesn't say anything about whether it should or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The Silicon Valley credo is **driving** the society to develop rapidly."

means:

"The Silicon Valley credo is **forcing or causing** the society to develop rapidly."

Answer (score 1):

I think your back translation has not expressed the Chinese very well.

A "credo" is (literally) a statement of belief, with an extended meaning of "collection of beliefs" or "mindset".

The meaning therefore is simple enough.

1. This set of beliefs causes society to develop rapidly.

You may infer:

2. It is because the people in this society have this set of beliefs that society develops rapidly.

I think that (2) is what your textbook is trying to convey. But for me, 1. and 2. are the same.  I can infer 2 from 1, since a set of beliefs can't cause anything unless people hold those beliefs. That is obvious and doesn't need to be stated.

Now, the sentence doesn't say what the beliefs *are*, only their effect.  I suppose they are things like "hard work" and "individual freedom".  But note that "the belief that society should develop rapidly" doesn't have to be one of the beliefs.

Finally, I think most people reading this would assume that Silicon Valley society *does* develop rapidly. This isn't actually stated. It would be possible that the credo is pushing for rapid change, but other factors are holding it back, but that seems very unlikely. It is most likely that society is developing rapidly, because if not the author would want to mention what is holding it back.

So the interpretation "People in the Silicon Valley believe that they should drive the society to develop quickly, but it isn't for other reasons” isn't the correct interpretation.

Comment: I apologize for my lack of ability to articulate things well. My point is that why the sentence can not mean “People in the Silicon Valley  believe that they should drive the society to develop quickly.” ? (Maybe it can be possible that they believe they should drive the society to develop, but in fact did not for various reasons.) So this is different from what you say is the meaning of the sentence (The society indeed develops quickly.)

Comment: I've addressed this comment now in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is very clear.